# How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to find an element using only the data attribute in html, and then grab that value?

For example, with this line inside an html doc:

```
<ul data-bin="Sdafdo39">
```

How do I retrieve `Sdafdo39` by searching the entire html doc for the element that has the `data-bin` attribute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `find_all` method to get all the tags and filtering based on "data-bin" found in its attributes will get us the actual tag which has got it. Then we can simply extract the value corresponding to it, like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<ul data-bin="Sdafdo39">"""
bs = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
print [item["data-bin"] for item in bs.find_all() if "data-bin" in item.attrs]
# ['Sdafdo39']
```

Comment: i cant make a html_doc variable because one of my element's attribute is not always the same.
<section class='{random_characters_here}' data-type='word-definition-card'>
I want to get the class by data-type

I also tried to do this

section = soup.find_all('section', data_type='word-definition-card')

but it just doesnt work :P

Answer (score 43):

A little bit more accurate

```
[item['data-bin'] for item in bs.find_all('ul', attrs={'data-bin' : True})]
```

This way, the iterated list only has the ul elements that has the attr you want to find

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
html_doc = """<ul class="foo">foo</ul><ul data-bin="Sdafdo39">"""
[item['data-bin'] for item in bs.find_all('ul', attrs={'data-bin' : True})]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could solve this with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) in just a couple of lines:

First, import and turn the html into a `Soup` object:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """<ul data-bin="Sdafdo39">"""
soup = Soup(html)
```

Then you can just search for the "ul" tag and extract the href attribute:

```py
soup.find("ul").attrs["data-bin"]
# Sdafdo39
```

Comment: Short and sweet! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative if one prefers to use CSS selectors via `select()` instead of `find_all()`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<ul class="foo">foo</ul><ul data-bin="Sdafdo39">"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# Select
soup.select('ul[data-bin]')
```