# Accessing data within the class description with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a website but the data that I am interested in lies within the class description:

```
<td class="cars" horse-power="276"></td>
```

To parse the whole table im using:

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'): 
    column = row.find_all('td')
```

I tried various different methods but nothing works so far. How can i access this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem either

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'): 
    for td in row.find_all('td'):
        print td.attrs['class']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'): 
    td_class = [td.get('class') for td in row.find_all('td')]
    td_horse-power = [td.get('horse-power') for td in row.find_all('td')]
```