# (Beautiful Soup) Get data inside a button tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to scrape out an ImageId inside a button tag, want to have the result:

```
"25511e1fd64e99acd991a22d6c2d6b6c".
```

When I try:

```
drawing_url = drawing_url.find_all('button', class_='inspectBut')['onclick']
```

it doesn't work. Giving an error-

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Input =

```
for article in soup.find_all('div', class_='dojoxGridRow'):
drawing_url = article.find('td', class_='dojoxGridCell', idx='3')
drawing_url = drawing_url.find_all('button', class_='inspectBut')
if drawing_url:
    for e in drawing_url:
        print(e)
```

Output =

```
    <button class="inspectBut" href="#" 
        onclick="window.open('getImg?imageId=25511e1fd64e99acd991a22d6c2d6b6c&amp;
                 timestamp=1552011572288','_blank', 'toolbar=0, 
                 menubar=0, modal=yes, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, 
                 height='+$(window).height()+', width='+$(window).width())" 
         title="Open Image" type="button">
    </button>
... 
...
```

Comment: I am not an expert but shouldnt `[onclick]`  be `['onclick']`

Comment: sorry typo i actually typed ['onclick'], it gives error :    drawing_url = drawing_url.find_all('button', class_='inspectBut')['onclick']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

Comment: providing an url/sufficient source html helps elicit better quality answers and likely faster resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
import re

#for all the buttons
btn_onlclick_list = [a.get('onclick') for a in soup.find_all('button')]
for click in btn_onlclick_list:
     a = re.findall("imageId=(\w+)", click)[0]
     print(a)
```

Comment: beautiful! it works! Thank you so much!! how do i loop through all then?

Comment: dont know how to get all buttons, print(click) only show the first button. and import array to re is not allowed. do you have any idea?

Comment: for multiple button: `[btn.get("onclick") for btn in soup.find_all('button')]`

Comment: can you edit your code to complete your answer please, many thanks!!

Comment: @LucasK.C.L Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be searching for

```
button_list = soup.find_all('button', {'class': 'inspectBut'})
```

That will give you the button array and you can later get url field by

```
 [button['getimg?imageid'] for button in button_list]
```

You will still need to do some parsing, but I hope this can get you on the right track.

Your mistake here was that you need to search correct property `class` and look for correct html tag, which is, ironically, `getimg?imageid`.

Comment: Your answer works best , i tested it out, thanks a lot. should be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check whether the attribute is present or not.
`tag.attrs` returns a list of attributes present in the current tag

Consider the following Code.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a="""
<td>
<button class='hi' onclick="This Data">
<button class='hi' onclick="This Second">
</td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml')
print([btn['onclick'] for btn in soup.find_all('button',class_='hi') if 'onclick' in btn.attrs])
```

**Output:**

```
['This Data','This Second']
```

or you can simply do this

```
[btn['onclick'] for btn in soup.find_all('button', attrs={'class' : 'hi', 'onclick' : True})]
```

Comment: getting the same error, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Yes. Using print([btn['onclick'] for btn in soup.find_all('button',class_='inspectBut') if 'onclick' in btn.attrs])