# Problem: how to get a list of tag attribute values with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, time, beautifulsoup, datetime-select

I want to scrape from the website of a local cinema and get all times, when a certain film is running.

I found the table in which the times are listed in the following form:

```
[<time datetime="2020-01-31T21:15:00+01:00">21:15</time>].
```

If I use beautifulsoup as x.find_all('time'). I get all the times in the form shown above. 
But I only want the 'datetime' so in this case **2020-01-31T21: 15: 00 + 01: 00.** Now when I search for x.find_all('time')['datetime'] I get the following error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Can someone tell me how I use beautifulsoup to create a list in which all 'datetime' are collected?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Beautiful Soup) Get data inside a button tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056003/beautiful-soup-get-data-inside-a-button-tag)

Comment: Oops -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24197922 is the "deeper" duplicate. Still: just use `print ([a.get('datetime') for a in soup.find_all('time')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x.find_all('time')
```

will return a list.  So you'll have to get an item from the list before you can get the "datetime" attribute.

```
x.find_all('time')[0]['datetime']
```

will probably do it.