# Beautiful Soup filtering for keywords/attributes (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, filtering

I want to scrape the data of a websitse using Beautiful Soup and requests, and I've almost got what I want, but I can't find a way to filter the final steps:

Here is my code:

```
variants = soup.find('div', class_='product-configure')
print(variants)
```

This prints the following:

```
<div class="product-configure">
<select id="custom-variants">
<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Maak een keuze</option>
<option data-status="available" data-value="177379037">Size : EU 40.5 (US 7) 
</option>
<option data-status="available" data-value="177379043">Size : EU 41.5 (US 8) 
</option>
<option data-status="available" data-value="177379223">Size : EU 42.5 (US 9) 
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

How can I filter this so it only prints all the numbers in "data-value"?
(e.g "177379037" as output for the first line)

Here is the HTML:

```
          <div class="gui-select">
                  <div class="product-configure">
                        <select id="custom-variants">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
                            <option data-value="177379037" data-status="available">Size : EU 40.5 (US 7)</option>
                            <option data-value="177379043" data-status="available">Size : EU 41.5 (US 8)</option>
                            <option data-value="177379223" data-status="available">Size : EU 42.5 (US 9)</option>


        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use soup.find_all() and use a dict with attributes

```
options = soup.find_all("option", {"data-value": True})
```

Result:

```
for o in options:
    print(o.attrs["data-value"])
```

---

```
177379037
177379043
177379223
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thanks. Do you also have an idea how I could filter out just the plain text that begins with "Size: "? Since it is not an attribute

Comment: I use XPATH for that, have to use before BeautifulSoup object, check some example. I let you the xpath example for your question: xpath_optiopns: "//options[@data-value and contains(text(), 'Size :')]"

Comment: @VietNaM What you're asking for is easy with just BeautifulSoup and list comprehensions, as well. For example, `[o.get_text() for o in doc.find_all("option", {"data-value": True}) if o.get_text().startswith("Size :")]` returns `['Size : EU 40.5 (US 7)', 'Size : EU 41.5 (US 8)', 'Size : EU 42.5 (US 9)']`. If you want a `dict` of `data-value` to text contents, use a `dict` comprehension: `{o.attrs["data-value"]: o.get_text() for o in doc.find_all("option", {"data-value": True})}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use class with attribute css selector

```
items = [item['data-value'] for item in soup.select('.product-configure [data-value]')]
```

If there is only the one class to consider you could use the id for the select

```
items = [item['data-value'] for item in soup.select('#custom-variants [data-value]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `find_all` to get all the `<option>` tags, then print off the `data-value` attribute. Notice though that not all `option` tags have that attribute, so I put a `try` in there to continue if there is no `data-value` found.

```
html = '''         <div class="gui-select">
                  <div class="product-configure">
                        <select id="custom-variants">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an option</option>
                            <option data-value="177379037" data-status="available">Size : EU 40.5 (US 7)</option>
                            <option data-value="177379043" data-status="available">Size : EU 41.5 (US 8)</option>
                            <option data-value="177379223" data-status="available">Size : EU 42.5 (US 9)</option>


        </div>'''

import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

elem = soup.find_all('option')
for each in elem:
    try:
        print (each['data-value'])
    except:
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
177379037
177379043
177379223
```