# How to control if a string is present in a website through python

Tags: python, html, http

I'm trying to identify if a string like `"data=sold"` is present in a website.

Now I'm using requests and a while loop but I need it to be faster:

```
  response = requests.get(link)
  if ('data=sold' in response.text):
```

It works well but it is not fast , is there a way to "request" only the part of the website I need to make the researching faster ?

Comment: That completely depends on the website, but most likely not.

Comment: Is it an html attribute? ie data attribute with value = sold?

Answer (score 1):

I think you response.text is html right ?

to avoid to search string you can try with Beautiful Soup [Doc here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = response.text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
[item['data-sold] for item in bs.find_all('ul', attrs={'data-sold' : True})]
```

can see other ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

or maybe I think a about parallel for loop in python

we can make many requests in same time

Comment: would it be faster ?

Comment: yep It's will be more faster if do parallel loop but please remind if we hit many requests in same time at same site they may be detect our requests as spam and block us

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, it depends on the website/server if you can only request a part of the page. Since it is a website I would think it's not possible.

If the website is really really big, the only way I can currently think of to make the search faster is to process the data just in time. When you call requests.get(link), the site will be downloaded before you can process the data. You maybe could try to call

```
 r = requests.get(link, stream=True)
```

instead. And then iterate through all the lines:

```
 for line in r:
    if ('data=sold' in line):
       print("hooray")
```

Of course you could also analyze the raw stream and just skip x bytes, use the aiohttp library, ... maybe you need to give some more information about your problem.