# Extracting the Link from this HTML

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract some information from this site using beautifulsoup. I am familiar with extracting tags by class/attributes, but how can I extract the url from "tr data-url"?

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amcham.org.sg/events-list/?item%5Bdate_start%5D=07%2F05%2F2019&item%5Bdate_end%5D=09/17/2019#page-1"

webpage_response = requests.get(url)
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")


table = soup.find_all("tbody")
for i in table:
    rows = i.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

```
<tr data-url="https://www.amcham.org.sg/event/8914">
<td class="date">July 09, 2019</td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

Answer (score 0):

Try (picking up on your code):

```
for row in rows:
    myurl = [item['data-url'] for item in bs.find_all('row', attrs={'data-url' : True})]
    print(myurl)
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24198276/1447509