# How to extract a specific string inside a tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am able to parse a section of a website, however I want to further extract a specific string from the section with Python/BeautifulSoup

**My code:**

```
    section = soup.find("div", {"class": "listing-col col-sm-16 col-md-12 col-lg-13 col"})

    for span in section.select('div.btn-group'):
        print(span)
        exit() # just print one and exit
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<shortlist-directive data-shortlist-id="10981410" ng-controller="ShortlistController" ng-init="setCurrentListingIdSrp('10981410'); setGAEventDataSrp({&quot;ss_cg_listing_id&quot;:10981410,&quot;listingid&quot;:10981410,&quot;make&quot;:&quot;Audi&quot;,&quot;model&quot;:&quot;TT&quot;,&quot;transmission&quot;:&quot;Automatic&quot;,&quot;body_type&quot;:&quot;Coupe&quot;,&quot;location&quot;:&quot;Maddington, WA&quot;,&quot;Kms&quot;:&quot;54,570 km&quot;,&quot;featured&quot;:&quot;No&quot;,&quot;seller_type&quot;:&quot;USED Dealer ad&quot;,&quot;ss_cg_products&quot;:&quot;&quot;});"></shortlist-directive>
</div>
```

**Question:**

From the *output* I want to extract `10981410` from `data-shortlist-id="10981410"` inside of `shortlist-directive`. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, use CSS selector `shortlist-directive[data-shortlist-id]` (select tag `<shortlist-directive>` with attribute `data-shortlist-id`:

```
txt = '''<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<shortlist-directive data-shortlist-id="10981410" ng-controller="ShortlistController" ng-init="setCurrentListingIdSrp('10981410'); setGAEventDataSrp({&quot;ss_cg_listing_id&quot;:10981410,&quot;listingid&quot;:10981410,&quot;make&quot;:&quot;Audi&quot;,&quot;model&quot;:&quot;TT&quot;,&quot;transmission&quot;:&quot;Automatic&quot;,&quot;body_type&quot;:&quot;Coupe&quot;,&quot;location&quot;:&quot;Maddington, WA&quot;,&quot;Kms&quot;:&quot;54,570 km&quot;,&quot;featured&quot;:&quot;No&quot;,&quot;seller_type&quot;:&quot;USED Dealer ad&quot;,&quot;ss_cg_products&quot;:&quot;&quot;});"></shortlist-directive>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('shortlist-directive[data-shortlist-id]')['data-shortlist-id'] )
```

Prints:

```
10981410
```

---

*Or*: If you don't know the name of tag, only attribute name, you can use:

```
soup.select_one('[data-shortlist-id]')['data-shortlist-id']
```

Comment: I don't just one, but for the whole  `data-shortlist-id`s within...

Comment: @3kstc If you want all tags with attributes `data-shortlist-id`, you can do `soup.select('[data-shortlist-id]')`