# Scraping JSON from div data attribute with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the chart data stored in div `data-moves=` list of dictionaries from this bs4.element.Tag (data) and cant seem to figure out why it's not working.

The data I want is:

```html
<div id="event-swing-container" data-moves='[{"name":"Change since opening","data":[["Magomed Ankalaev",-73],["Azamat Murzakanov",-56],....,["Marlon Moraes",1]],"visible":false}]' id="event-swing-container" style="height: 230px;"></div>
```

Here's my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = 'https://www.bestfightodds.com/events/ufc-2414'
page = requests.get(URL)

esoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
data = esoup.find('div', id='event-swing-container')
```

Comment: @ggorlen i added an image, hope that helps.  Thanks

Comment: @ggorlen Think i  fixed my post and added the minimal code possible, sorry for the trouble. Thanks again

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. Voted to reopen and upvoted. That said, [How find specific data attribute from html tag in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197922/how-find-specific-data-attribute-from-html-tag-in-beautifulsoup4) may be able to solve your problem, along with `json.loads()` once you have the contents of `data-moves`.

Comment: data.attrs actually returns the dictionary and then i used json.loads to convert over.  Thanks for helping with this silly question =) @ggorlen